# Remove gridview options

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, devexpress

How to remove "Show Group By Box" and "Remove This Column" from `GridView` menu? When I go to events there are no ShowGridMenu  event so [THIS](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A47.aspx?searchtext=hide%20context%20menu%20items&p=T4%7CP0%7C56) will not work for me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [GridView.PopupMenuShowing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_PopupMenuShowingtopic) event instead for this purpose.

```
private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e) {
            if(e.MenuType == GridMenuType.Column) 
                RemoveItem(e.Menu, GridLocalizer.Active.GetLocalizedString(GridStringId.MenuColumnRemoveColumn));
            else
                if(e.MenuType == GridMenuType.Group) 
                    RemoveItem(e.Menu, GridLocalizer.Active.GetLocalizedString(GridStringId.MenuGroupPanelShow));
        }

        private void RemoveItem(GridViewMenu menu, string caption) { 
            for(int i = 0; i < menu.Items.Count; i ++)
                if(menu.Items[i].Caption == caption) {
                    menu.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull! You should remove some of the outdated answers on your website, they can be confusing.